# findIndex with two dimensional Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find the index of a value in an object in a two dimensional array. The array is structured like this:

```
trips.push({
    station: stationIDs[i],
    stationtrips: ({
        [theid]: station[theid], // This is what I need to find the Index of
        cnt: station.cnt,
        tps: station.tps
    })
})
```

What I tried so far:

```
// First Find index of station
stationIndex = trips.findIndex(y => y.station == stationIDs[i]);
// If exists, find index of sub-station
if(stationIndex !== -1) {
    subStationIndex = trips[stationIndex].stationtrips.findIndex(x => x[theid] == station[theid]);

}
```

I am getting this error:

> trips[stationIndex].stationtrips.findIndex is not a function

Question: Does `findIndex` not work with this structure? What is the proper way to handle this?

-- Update: The console.log of the array (up until it finds a stationindex and then fails at the substationindex):

[image]

Comment: The value of `stationtrips` isn't an array.

Comment: The code you show doesn't seem to have the line that is referenced in the error message.

Comment: Corrected the error message.

Comment: @quentin if we close all questions because *they were answered already here*, we loose the general idea of SO to help people learning to properly write code... ( this is not really an exact duplicate)

Comment: @Jonasw updated the question.

Comment: @ffritz so theid="eid" ?

Comment: @Jonasw Correct. It can change, which is why `[theid]` is there.

Comment: @ffritz ok, so you want the station where eid==174 for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147706/discussion-between-ffritz-and-jonas-w).